# Global variables not working in C kernel .rdata section

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, kernel, ld

I don't know why global variables are not working. I think that there is a problem with the address of **.rdata** section. I don't know how to link my kernel to make this section visible at specific memory area.

I'm using Windows 7

**Note: I dont want to use GRUB Bootloader, instead I want to use my own bootloader.**

This is my files:

bootsect.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000 ; The same one we used when linking the kernel
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl ; Remember that the BIOS sets us the boot drive in 'dl' on boot
    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET ; Read from disk and store in 0x1000
    mov dh, 2
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    pusha
    ; reading from disk requires setting specific values in all registers
    ; so we will overwrite our input parameters from 'dx'. Let's save it
    ; to the stack for later use.
    push dx
    mov ah, 0x02 ; ah <- int 0x13 function. 0x02 = 'read'
    mov al, dh   ; al <- number of sectors to read (0x01 .. 0x80)
    mov cl, 0x02 ; cl <- sector (0x01 .. 0x11)
                 ; 0x01 is our boot sector, 0x02 is the first 'available' sector
    mov ch, 0x00 ; ch <- cylinder (0x0 .. 0x3FF, upper 2 bits in 'cl')
    ; dl <- drive number. Our caller sets it as a parameter and gets it from BIOS
    ; (0 = floppy, 1 = floppy2, 0x80 = hdd, 0x81 = hdd2)
    mov dh, 0x00 ; dh <- head number (0x0 .. 0xF)
    ; [es:bx] <- pointer to buffer where the data will be stored
    ; caller sets it up for us, and it is actually the standard location for int 13h
    int 0x13      ; BIOS interrupt
    jc $ ; if error (stored in the carry bit)
    pop dx
    cmp al, dh    ; BIOS also sets 'al' to the # of sectors read. Compare it.
    jne $
    popa
    ;call switch_to_pm ; disable interrupts, load GDT,  etc. Finally jumps to 'BEGIN_PM'
    cli ; 1. disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; 2. load the GDT descriptor
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; 3. set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ; 4. far jump by using a different segment
    jmp $ ; Never executed
gdt_start: ; don't remove the labels, they're needed to compute sizes and jumps
    ; the GDT starts with a null 8-byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
; GDT for code segment. base = 0x00000000, length = 0xfffff
; for flags, refer to os-dev.pdf document, page 36
gdt_code: 
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31
; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
; some flags changed, again, refer to os-dev.pdf
gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:
; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit), always one less of its true size
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)
; define some constants for later use
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
[bits 32] ; using 32-bit protected mode
; this is how constants are defined
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f ; the color byte for each character
[bits 32]
init_pm: ; we are now using 32-bit instructions
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 5. update the segment registers
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    ;mov ax, 11c4h
    mov ds, ax
    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; 6. update the stack right at the top of the free space
    mov esp, ebp
    call KERNEL_OFFSET ; Give control to the kernel
    jmp $ ; Stay here when the kernel returns control to us (if ever)
BOOT_DRIVE db 0 ; It is a good idea to store it in memory because 'dl' may get overwritten
; padding
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

kernel.c

```
void write_string( int colour, const char *string )
{
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
    while( *string != 0 )
    {
        *video++ = *string++;
        *video++ = colour;
    }
}

void ClearScreen()
{
    char* video = (char*) 0xB8000;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 80*25)
    {
        *video++ = 0;
        *video++ = 0;
        i++;
    }
}

char* str1 = "from global";

void start() 
{
    ClearScreen();
    char str2[] = "from stack";
    write_string(7, str1); //This is not working
    write_string(7, str2); //This is working but I don't want that
}
```

kernel_entry.asm

```
[bits 32]
[extern _start]
call _start
jmp $
```

Makefile

```
GCC = gcc.exe
NASM = nasm.exe
LD = ld.exe
OBJCOPY = objcopy.exe
QEMU = qemu-system-i386.exe

build:
    $(GCC) -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
    $(NASM) kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
    $(LD) -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j .text kernel.tmp kernel.bin
    $(NASM)  bootsect.asm -f bin -o bootsect.bin
    copy /b bootsect.bin + kernel.bin os-image.bin
    $(QEMU) -fda os-image.bin

clean:
    del kernel.o
    del kernel_entry.o
    del kernel.tmp
    del kernel.bin
    del bootsect.bin
    del os-image.bin
```

Comment: `str1` is not heap allocated. It is a global variable and inoted to literal string put in "read-only-data" section which gets mapped into the process space as read-only. BTW why are you writing that `str1` is not working?

Comment: Because it is not printed to screen

Comment: Did you try to switch printfs? I mean to print str2 first.

Comment: I already printed it alone, it print garbage or nothing, I need to `objcopy` the .rdata and put it somewhere with the kernel, and that is the problem

Comment: Having no linker script is not a good sign: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Linking_the_Kernel Try to confirm that your final binary actually contains all the data that you want, using e.g. `objdump`

Comment: How to use the linker script without GRUB Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own bootloader and startup code of your application, the copy of rdata (or rodata) to your memory must be performed by your init code.
Same thing for bss section, is your startup code that has the responsability to reset to 0 the whole memory where global variables of that section are placed.

Comment: But how to fix the address of global variables ... ?